# univocity csv parser setTypeOfColumns not working

Tags: java, csv, univocity

This test fails with: expected: <java.lang.Integer> but was: <java.lang.String>

```
@Test
public void testSetTypeOfColumns() throws IOException {
    String data = "ID,NAME" + System.lineSeparator() + "2,Chris";
    InputStream csvStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(new CsvParserSettings() {
        {
            setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    parser.beginParsing(csvStream);

    parser.getRecordMetadata().setTypeOfColumns(Integer.class, "ID");
    parser.getRecordMetadata().setTypeOfColumns(String.class, "NAME");

    Record record = parser.parseNextRecord();
    Map<String, Object> map = record.toFieldObjectMap();
    assertEquals(Integer.class, map.get("ID").getClass());
}
```

Is there something wrong in my code is this a bug?

Comment: rmd.convertFields(new IntegerConversion()).add("ID"); did the job, setTypeOfColumns seems to be more for pojo creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Converts the record into a map of Object values. Conversions must be
> registered using RecordMetaData.convertFields(Conversion[]) or
> RecordMetaData.convertIndexes(Conversion[]) (Conversion[])}. Columns
> without a known conversion will have their values put into the map as
> plain Strings.

http://docs.univocity.com/parsers/2.7.2/index.html?com/univocity/parsers/common/record/Record.html

Have a look at their tutorial how to map to a simple POJO.

https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial#using-annotations-to-map-your-java-beans

```
// BeanListProcessor converts each parsed row to an instance of a given class, then stores each instance into a list.
BeanListProcessor<TestBean> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<TestBean>(TestBean.class);

CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
parserSettings.setProcessor(rowProcessor);
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
parser.parse(getReader("/examples/bean_test.csv"));

// The BeanListProcessor provides a list of objects extracted from the input.
List<TestBean> beans = rowProcessor.getBeans();
```